# Can we have a [meeting] about these tags? (I can send out a [meeting-request] if so)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting) has 45 questions. It has several similar tags as well: [live-meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-meeting) has 11 questions. [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) has 30. Finally, we have [conference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conference) with 98 questions. None of them have any tag wikis.

In most cases, these questions are about some system related to meetings or conference calls, so I *guess* that the way they're being used is on topic, but the broader meaning of the tag isn't on-topic here.

It's also unclear what these are supposed to contribute to the questions.

Can we burninate these? (The low number of items should make this request quick).

**Edit:** [meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting) and [live-meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-meeting) were burninated under the abbreviated process. [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) will be deferred for now pending consultation with a trusted user on the matter, and [conference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conference) will be moved to its own request since it's too large for the abbreviated process.

Comment: [tag:conference] is the one giving me the most doubts. We don't have an alternative tag for starting conference calls, but we might not need one at all. Too many questions to do a quick burninate on that tag, though, so it will have to go through the entire process.

Comment: I'd wager that at least 70% (I just checked seven, five were clearly wrong, I don't know about the other two) of the conference tags are erroneous. I just removed it on two that were related to conferences the person attended (so the tag is arguably not relevant), and one where the person wanted something to show up in a conference room. I'd burninate.

Comment: Probably it is best to make one burninate request per tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting)

[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. The contents of on-topic questions will, at best, be about programming meeting-related applications. The tag is ambiguous since someone could get the wrong idea that questions about meetings and other work-related issues are on-topic.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, since it could either mean "questions about programming meeting-related things" or "how to have meetings".

---

Conclusion: burninate it with fire.

I think the same conclusions can be made about [live-meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-meeting) and [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request).

Comment: [Live Meeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Live_Meeting) was a piece of Microsoft software, so that tag isn't as obviously bad as it might seem. On the other hand, the software has been discontinued, and it doesn't look there are many questions currently having that tag that need to stick around.

Comment: @CodyGray It is still ambiguous then. Only half of the questions listed with that tag seems to be about that piece of software. And still, did that software have an API or such? If not, it the tag is probably not relevant, it would be similar to having a tag for MS Paint or whatever.

Comment: A tag is not ambiguous just because you aren't familiar with its intended purpose. The Ruby tag isn't ambiguous because people might want to ask questions about gemstone settings.

Comment: @CodyGray Only 3 of the 11 questions have anything to do with MS Live Meeting as far as I can tell, and all 3 of them are close-worthy, so the tag really isn't needed IMHO. It's really not adding anything to the remaining 8 questions and it's not clear to me why the OPs there even thought that they should use that tag.

Comment: @CodyGray Those who are using the live-meeting tag but aren't asking about the MS product, are asking about "live meetings" ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848830/live-streaming-a-video-file)). Therefore it is ambiguous. If the purpose of the tag is MS Live Meeting and nothing else, it should perhaps be re-tagged ms-live-meeting or some such.